# VBA - Contando o número de células preenchidas na linha

Tags: vba, contador

Olá, pessoal.
Estou tentando criar um código responsável por ler a quantidade de células preenchidas nas linhas.. Tentei desta forma porém não tive sucesso.

```
  For b = 1 To rMaior
         contador = Worksheets("1").Range("b:b").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
                MsgBox contador
  Next b
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Creio que sua fórmula possui um pequeno erro... tente usar o nome da planilha conforme abaixo:

```
MsgBox Plan1.Range("b:b").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Altere seu código para isso:

```
  For b = 1 To rMaior
         contador = Worksheets("1").Rows(b).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
         MsgBox contador
  Next b
```

Esse código considera que você quer contar *n* linhas da planilha chamada 1. Além disso, deve ter uma variável chamada rMaior declarada e que especifica a última linha que deverá ser contada. Assim, o código percorrerá da linha 1 até rMaior contando o número de células não vazias por linha.